# Use Pagination in Ruby when fetching data with a SQL query (mysql2 type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, kaminari

I have a query in my controller which looks like this:

```
@temp = connection.execute("select test_id from mastertest limit 500;")
```

Now I display the results fetched here in a table in my view. But I want to limit the results to say 10 rows per page. I know I can use will_paginate and kaminari

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

But can anyone give me the exact syntax or a sample code to apply pagination in my case of an SQL query and how I can display results in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want pagination using sql query, then you need to use mysql **offset** keyword with a **limit** clause. So you will get exact pagination like results. I hope below code will help you.

```
current_page = current_page || 1
per_page = 10
records_fetch_point = (current_page - 1) * per_page

query = "select test_id from mastertest limit #{per_page} 
         offset #{records_fetch_point};"

@temp = connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: Beware of SQL injection attack

Comment: My query is quite complex than what I have put up here. Unfortunately I cannot use LIMIT in that. Can someone explain me how paginate_by_sql would work here ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use `mastertest` model? instead of `connection.execute`
(models are in app/models)

```rb
#using kaminari
relation = Mastertest.order(:id).limit(500).page(1).per(10)

relation.each do |row|
  puts row.test_id
end
```

Comment: It's a quite complex query. I just put up a simple query to simplify things. I'll edit the changes.

Comment: You will need to add order coditions to the Santosh's answer.  Otherwise you have chances to get different results every time you request for a page.